# Why does certbot "version" domain certificate folders

Tags: versioning, certbot

I recently switched to route53 so I could “re-issue” an existing certificate as a wildcard certificate for my domain “mydomain”.

The valid non-wildcard certs files were created by

```
certbot certonly -d mydomain.com,foo.mydomain.com,boo.mydomain.com
```

and in the appropriately named directories:

```
/live/mydomain
/archive/mydomain
```

Upon running

```
certbot certonly --dns-route53 -d mydomain.com,*.mydomain.com”
```

certbot proceeded to make NEW “versioned” folders, rather than use the exiting ones:

```
/live/mydomain-0001
/archive/mydomain-0001
```

I no longer need the non-wildcard cert, I’d like to get rid of the -0001 folders. so my questions are:

1. Why did certbot do this?
2. Is there a certbot command that will clean this up?
3. If not, can I “move” the “-0001” files into the original folders (of course Id have to redo the soft links)?
4. I’m hoping for a simple way to clean this up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, it appears that the original non-wild card cert was created with

```
certbot certonly --cert-name mydomain.com -d mydomain.com,foo.mydomain.com
```

but the subsequent wild-card cert was generated without the --cert-name option, so certbot likely saw the -d name string as a reason for differentiating...

Hope this helps someone...